Using launchWebAuthFlow with Supabase for Chrome Extension Authentication
I am trying to authenticate a Chrome extension with Supabase. This requires me to use launchWebAuthFlow, which takes the authURL that Supabase generates. It has this form:
https://<clientID>/auth/v1/verify?token=<some_token?>&type=magiclink&redirect_to=https://<chromeURL>.chromiumapp.org/src/auth_handler.html
However according to Mozilla Docs, the URL that I need to pass needs a redirect_uri parameter instead, not redirect_to.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/identity/launchWebAuthFlow
Also does launchWebAuthFlow require the token? How would I get it?
Supabase allows me to just generate the URL instead of sending it, but I don’t think that’s the correct solution
https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-admin-generatelink?example=generate-a-magic-link
This is my current code:
const redirectUri = chrome.identity.getRedirectURL("src/auth_handler.html");
const authUrl = `${process.env.REACT_APP_SUPABASE_URL}/auth/v1/verify?redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirectUri)}`;  chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(    
     {             url: authUrl,          interactive: true }
)

